# How do I add data to end of object in ReactJS Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am trying to setup a multi checkbox page where the data is filtered by checkboxes from different categories using ReactJS hooks.

I am adding the state for which checkbox is selected as an object - i.e.

```
{
    color: 'orange',
    shape: 'square'
}
```

My issue is that when I add something with a similar key this gets copied over so the state is fine as above but if I select the color filter red, the color orange filter is removed.

My code is as follows -

```
setCheckboxes(checkboxes => ({
  ...checkboxes, [e.target.id]: e.target.dataset.item
}))
```

What can I do to modify the above code so that I can have 2 or more filters with the same key, that would allow my data to look like this -

```
{
    color: 'orange',
    color: 'green',
    shape: 'square',
}
```

I am not too familar with a state library but would be open to using maybe the React Context API.

Answer (score 2):

when you spread an object into a new object, if there are any matching keys the last one in declared will be the one in the final object.
Heres an example in case my wording is not too precise, in this one we spread first the object with a key named color, into a new object with a key after the spread operation:

```js
let baseObject = {
  color: "red"
}

let fromSpeadedObj = {
  ...baseObject,
  color: "blue"
}

console.log(fromSpeadedObj)
```

Here is the same example backwards, to show that the last key|value entered is the one that remains in the final object:

```js
let baseObject = {
  color: "red"
}

let fromSpeadedObj = {
  color: "blue",
  ...baseObject
}

console.log(fromSpeadedObj)
```

In fact when you write a literal with duplicated keys, the last one of the repeated ones is the one stored

```js
let obj1 = {
    name: "first",
    name: "second"
}

console.log(obj1)
```

Comment: Thanks Mario. I can see that that wouldn't work now. Would the best option be to have the value as an array ie
```
let obj1 = {
    name: [ "first", "second"]
};
```

Then how could I convert my code above use an array in the instance of a  duplicate key

Comment: @peco60052 If you want a key to have multiple values using an array as value would be a good option. Alternatives are using a Set, Map, Object or any other complex object. They all have their own strengths and weaknesses. Depending on you use-case some might be better suited than others. Without knowing anything about your usage I would suggest using an array.

Answer (score 2):

What you currently have implemented works. The reason why adding a filter color red removes orange is because there cannot be two same keys in an object like

```js
{
    color: 'orange',
    color: 'green',
    shape: 'square',
}
```

Although, you can refactor the state to accept an array of colors and shapes like

```js
{
    color: ['orange', 'red'],
    shape: ['square', 'circle'],
}
```

A full implementation can be written like

```js
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({ color: [], shape: [] })

const setCheckbox = (e) => {
   // filters[e.target.id] -> 'shape' | 'color'
   setFilters((filters) => {
      return {
         ...filters,
         [e.target.id]: [...filters[e.target.id], e.target.dataset.item]
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Isaac - I can see this working nicely when console.logging the filters state inside my setCheckbox function but when I run it in the return render, the state is not updating.

Any idea what causes this? So the state is not available to modify for filtering.

Comment: The react dev tools are not updating either

Comment: [React recommends not mutating the state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly), instead create a copy and set it as the new state. `setFilters(filters => ({...filters, [e.target.id]: [...filters[e.target.id], e.target.dataset.item]}))`. This looks a bit clumsy, but can be simplified if needed by using [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead of [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

Comment: @3limin4t0r I feel `useReducer` might be on overkill for this. Setting an action like in redux seems over the top ish. Although, thanks for pointing out mutating states directly.

Comment: I agree that it is overkill where it only for this line. However since we don't know the full context I linked it just in case. When state manipulation is cluttering the intent of the component, being able to for example do: `filtersDispatch({prop: e.target.id, action: "add", value: e.target.dataset.item})` does look quite nice. Good answer though.